# PDO updating row successfully and then failing?

Tags: mysql, pdo

A piece of my snippet:

```
//I retrieve a row(s) from the table i want to update

while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $row['url']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_exec($ch);
    $new_url = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
    curl_close($ch);

    if($new_url != $row['url']){           
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE footers SET footer = :footer WHERE id = :id");
        $stmt->bindParam(':id', $row['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(':footer', $new_url, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}
```

The problem is it will update one row on script run and then on next record fail. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Typo in `$row['url]` (missing single-quote)?

Comment: Can you post the exception you get?

Comment: No that was just a poor paste. The script doesn't have PHP errors. PDO error says 00000 which mean it worked, and I see the update in the table. If i run the script again it will update the next row like it was suppose to if the script didn't stop...

Comment: @Xint0 I don't get an exception thats the weird part. PDO exception gives me the ok status of 00000.

Comment: I think I figured it out. Give me a moment to test.

Comment: You're using the same variable for the statement you are looping through and your update statment. When you meet the condition of your if block `$stmt` is overwritten with your update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you are using the same variable name `$stmt` for both your fetch and update commands.  Furthermore, you might run into trouble iterating over the result and updating the underlying table at the same time, using the same connection.

I suggest to do the fetch and URL check on one loop and create an array of items to update.  Then iterate over the array on a second loop after closing the initial fetch result.  Also, take advantage of calling `prepare` once outside the loop, instead of on each iteration.

Comment: I just caught this right as you posted this. Thanks for quick answer.